# How to convert string value to XML file in C#?

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to convert string to XML file. 

I send XML data to another sever and get the respose.

So, I wrote this code.

```
rsp = req.GetResponse();           
using (HttpWebResponse response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string Response = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // This is respons andI want to read it
}
```

How to read the `string Response`? it is in XML format

Comment: Look up XDocument and XmlDocument. However, if you're only *saving* it to a file, just save the data as-is (the text received) - just be aware of potential encoding issues.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx, check this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Response` string corresponds to Xml. You can use this piece of code to *convert* / *save* it to a `Xml` file using `XDocument` class.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Response);
doc.Save("File Path");
```